# how to use basename-function to save filename in a variable

Tags: php, html, function

hello i thought it would be nicer to have clean urls.

so i would like to use basename for `basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'])`

i would like to save the basename into a variable that  i can use for header function like this:

```
$basename = basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);

if ($pref_language == 'af'){
    header('Location:en'.$basename;
    exit;
}
```

what does not work. so if there is someone who could tell me how to use this the right way i really would appreciate.

thanks alot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have a missing `)` in your code

try:

```
$basename = basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);

if ($pref_language == 'af'){
    header('Location:en'.$basename);
    exit;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are going down the wrong path.  You need to start your quest for clean URL's at the web server layer.As the web server needs to know how to route requests to do not actually match any filenames to an actual file for processing.   There are thousands of examples of how to do "clean URL's" or "server redirects" on Stack Overflow and the web at large.  If you are using Apache, specifically look for `mod_rewrite` commentary.